# How to download email messages as .msg files

Tags: java, email, outlook

Programatically using Java, is it possible to download and save emails from Exchange Server as .msg files?

If not, are there any formats possible, which can be opened with Outlook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions received were commercial options which for me is out of scope right now.
The second part in my question was if I can save in any other format. I have figured out that I can save them as .eml file which also can be opened in Outlook. This will solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Outlook Object Model (see MailItem.SaveAs) if you have a local Outlook profile configured to access the Exchange mailbox in question.

You can also use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) to dynamically connect to an Exchange mailbox ([RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`LogonExchangeMailbox`), iterate through the messages and save them in the MSG format ([RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`SaveAs`).

Comment: +1 for a solution. But I dont think I can use this as its not free. I have decided to save the messages as .eml